Write pandas dataframe to excel consume too much memory
I am using this code to write a dataframe into Excel file:
with pd.ExcelWriter(file_data, engine='xlsxwriter',engine_kwargs={"options": {"strings_to_formulas": False}}) as writer:
    df.to_excel(excel_writer=writer,sheet_name="data",index=False,)

where file_data = io.BytesIO(). It takes a lot of memory to finish this line. There are around 13k rows, and the result file is only around 43 MB, but the memory usage goes up to 1.1 GB. I also tried to chunk the dataframe into smaller pieces, but it consumes the same amount of memory as a whole. Is it designed to use so much memory, or am I using it wrong?

Have you tried using - {'constant_memory': True}
I think the cell objects created consume a lot of memory. The final xlsx format is compressed.
read more - https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_memory.html

@vamsi_s Yes, I did try that one. However, talking about dataframe, it's column based not row based. So use that one on a dataframe will only write one column finally.

Basically what you want to do is from the Pandas DataFrame, export it as a .csv or excel as you mecionated.
Just simply do DataFrame.to_excel()
Parameters here:
DataFrame.to_excel(excel_writer, *, sheet_name='Sheet1', na_rep='', float_format=None, columns=None, header=True, index=True, index_label=None, startrow=0, startcol=0, engine=None, merge_cells=True, inf_rep='inf', freeze_panes=None, storage_options=None, engine_kwargs=None)

Check documentation for more info about this: Pandas Data Frame to excel file
PD: What is the porpuses of your code when you want to do "with open(etc,etc,etc) as file:?
Make sure just to use this when readed some short txt files

There's no difference between two way. I still got 1.4 GB memory used even I remove with open statement.

Please, write your code to check it
